# Location auto complete using zip code

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, shipping, customer

On checkout page using local database if customer enter zip code then city/state /country auto complete.

Is any free extension available which completes the customer's city/state/country by using only their zip code?

Comment: I think this is impossible, because several countries (espacially in EU) have the same ZIP-type, so there could be the same number in two different countries as well. If you choose country and start typing ZIP, this extention can do the rest: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/asperience-addressautocomplete.html

Comment: the extension @StefanGregori suggested is very nice but as a small side note, since it uses a local database and not an API there is no guarantee that the data is up to date.

Comment: You are right @Stefan country selection is must for this. With little changes, extension you said works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Also thanks to @Sander for valuable suggestion.

Comment: @ganesh if you ever managed to get this working as desired, feel free to post the answer

Comment: @DavidManners I did. allow me some time I will post the answer.

Comment: @ganesh perfect :)

Comment: @ganesh If your problem was solved, please add your answer and accept it to mark this question as solved. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: is solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This extension provides the functionality requested, allowing a local database to be added and edited for any region:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/asperience-addressautocomplete.html

It does have some issues with 1.7.0.2+ which can be resolved by the following (taken from the Magento Connect page):

After installing this plugin the Region field was giving an error in the checkout. I solved this by editing the phtml files in the folder:

```
/app/design/frontend/<YOUR PACKAGE>/<YOUR THEME>/template/addresscomplete/checkout/onepage/
```

in billing.phtml :

Search for billingRegionUpdater

Replace line for:

```
var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');
```

and in shipping.phtml:

Search for shippingRegionUpdater
Replace line for :

```
var shippingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('shipping:country_id', 'shipping:region', 'shipping:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'shipping:postcode');
```